# react-navigation BottomTabNavigator cut off in production

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I am using the latest stable versions and it only happens on production (on all phones).

I added empty pages to be sure its not the height of the pages

Code:

```
const TestStackNavigatorr =  createBottomTabNavigator({
  HOME: {
    screen: Overview,
  }
})
const App = createAppContainer(TestStackNavigatorr)

export default App
```

Development image:

[image: development - OK]

Production:

[image: production - cut off]

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I had to remove Statusbar config in app.json and  and put this View with Constants.StatusBarHeight.

```
 return <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
          <View style={{height:Constants.statusBarHeight, backgroundColor: "#2F5851"}}/>
          <WrappedComponent />
   </View>
```